# Spring DriverManagerDataSource not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, datasource, spring-jdbc

I have a spring project and i want to create a bean with the DriverManagerDataSource class. I have looked around and found that most people with this issue didn't have spring-jdbc in their pom.xml so I triple checked and I do have the latest version in my pom.xml.

My rest-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

I have checked if its under "external libraries" (I use intelliJ) and i do see the class. Also when i try to type the classname the autocomplete finds it too.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you actually have this class in artifact that is built by IDEA. I guess it is WAR so check that it contains "spring-jdbc-.jar". If not check the scope of `spring-jdbc` dependency in "pom.xml". It should be `compile`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried putting the scoped to "compile" and it did not work (scope was not defined before). How would I check if it is in my WAR?

Comment: You can check your artifacts in project structure window and make sure that _spring-jdbc_ JAR is included into _WEB-INF/lib_ directory of exploded WAR artifact. After all WAR is just an uncompressed ZIP so you can open it using any archiver software. If artifact includes _spring-jdbc_ but actual WAR file doesn't, try to include artifact in project build and rebuild entire project.

Comment: I tried to include it, now it says FileNotFoundException: Access is denied

Comment: UPDATE: after rebuilding the project it can now find the file however it says it cant find certain classes within the jdbc library...

Comment: I have found that in the WAR, which i opened with WinRAR, the library I need is a file folder for whatever reason while the rest of the libraries are all JARs like I would expect. Any idea what this might mean?

Comment: Normally any dependencies should go to _WEB-INF/lib_ directory as JAR files. Classes from project itself should be put in _WEB-INF/classes_ directory. If you see unpacked library in _WEB-INF/lib_ probably it is an error and you should check artifacts in project structure window of IDE. Usually IntelliJ IDEA manages artifacts itself depending on applied Maven/Gradle plugins and this kind of issue may arise only when you create artifact manually.

Comment: I found that while i did have the dependency in my pom.xml, it was apparently not the right version. changing it to a slightly older version fixed the problem. Thank you for your help